# im trying to slide out and in a menubar with button click WPF

Tags: wpf, animation, styles

here is what im doing
i have a Buttons.xaml style file for styling my menu button

```
    <!-- Menu button -->
    <Style x:Key="MenuButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="50" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="True" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="border">

                        <Grid  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" 
                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}">

                            <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Width="20" Height="2" Fill="{StaticResource DarkGrayBrush}" Margin="0 0 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0, 0.5" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle1" Width="20" Height="2" Fill="{StaticResource DarkGrayBrush}" Margin="0 5 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0, 0.5" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle2" Width="20" Height="2" Fill="{StaticResource DarkGrayBrush}" Margin="0 10 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0, 0.5" />


                            <ContentPresenter  />

                        </Grid>


                    </Border>


                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource FaintWhiteBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>

                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="menuButton">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="gridMenu" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="0" To="100" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="gridMenu" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="100" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>
```

and here is my usercontrol view file
that has menu button itself with the styling and source name in my style that is supposed to be found by my event trigger when this button is clicked and slide out the grid 
but its not finding it

```
    <Grid>


        <!-- Menu button -->
        <Button x:Name="menuButton" Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}" />

        <!-- Menu bar -->       
        <Grid x:Name="gridMenu" Background="White" Width="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">

        </Grid>
```

when i run this code above this is the error message i get

```
InvalidOperationException: Cannot find element 'menuButton' targeted by this EventTrigger.
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triggers inside `ControlTemplate`s (or `DataTemplate`s) can only reference elements that are inside that template. The template doesn't "know" about anything outside of itself, so it can't interact with anything but its own parts.

If you want `menuButton` to interact with `gridMenu`, that has to be set up from a context/scope that knows about both of those things. In your case, this would be the `UserControl` where they are both declared.

If you wanted to implement something like this using an `EventTrigger` (with XAML only- no code), it would have to be done in the `ControlTemplate` of the `Control` that directly contained those two elements. Something like this:

```
        <Control>
            <Control.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Button Name="menuButton"/>
                        <Grid Name="gridMenu" Background="Green" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    </Grid>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger SourceName="menuButton" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="gridMenu" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="0" To="100" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="gridMenu" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="100" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>                
            </Control.Template>
        </Control>
```

The above is an example showing how to place a trigger in a scope that contains both elements, so that one can affect another. It's not a finished solution, but it should give you an idea of what I mean.

Keep in mind that I've just copy/pasted your `EventTrigger`s into my code. The triggers as you've written them only grow and then immediately shrink `menuGrid`, which I'm guessing isn't exactly what you want. You probably want it to grow, stay open, and then shrink at some later point. You'll need to work that out on your own (or ask another question), but assuming you want a second click of `menuButton` to close `menuGrid`, try using a [`ToggleButton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton?view=netframework-4.8) instead of a normal `Button` and using `EventTrigger`s in the `Checked` and `Unchecked` events.

One last thought: since you're making a `UserControl` you might want to consider declaring a `Boolean` property such as `IsOpen` and using that to trigger the `menuGrid` animation (via a `DataTrigger`) instead of having it triggered directly by `Button` click. This would let you open/close the menu from the `Window` that is housing the `UserControl`. All standard controls that have some sort of popup (such as `ComboBox` and `Expander`) have some such property that tells you the current state and allows you to change it from the outside.